# On edge mobile I am getting hover effects on elements when there should not be hover effects. I think it's a bug. Advice?

Tags: microsoft-edge

On edge mobile I am getting hover effects on elements even though the hover effects for the elements reside in the media breakpoint as follows:

```
@media screen and (hover: hover) { ... }
```

On Chrome, Firefox, and Safari the hover effects do not happen on mobile as expected. What's up? Is this a bug or is there a way to address this behavior?

UPDATE:
I'm on Android 9, Samsung S8, Edge 45.05.4.5036.

I also should mention my phone is a bit wonky. For some reason, chrome will not work at all, keeps crashing. Edge and Firefox work fine on my phone, but if this is behavior is not reproducible elsewhere then never mind for now. If I get a new phone and the problem persists I'll bring it back up. Thanks

Comment: Can you please inform us, which exact version of the Edge for mobile you are using for making this test? Are you using Apple or Android device? I make a test using Edge for mobile (Android) 45.05.24.5036 version and I am not able to produce the said behavior with your sample code. The code works as expected on my side. I suggest you provide more information about the issue that may help us to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

OK figured out the issue here finally after doing a little searching.

The media query needed to be set up as:
`@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {}`

`(pointer: fine)` makes sure that only a mouse pointer or similar can trigger the hover event on a device that allows touch and mouse input - like a laptop or my Samsung phone apparently. Probably best to always include the `(pointer: fine)`  unless you want touch events to trigger hover effects on those devices.